# Сделать чтобы один div перекрывал второй

Tags: html, css

Делаю выпадающее меню, но через него просвечивает текст div-а.

Как исправить- сделать чтобы меню закрывало div?

```css
.msgSub-menu{ margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
width:70px;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid #8ab113;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #ece5ae;
Border-radius: 3px;
z-index: 1; }

.messageMenu1{ 
margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
width:24px;
height: 24px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
bottom: -0px; } 

.messageBody { 
margin: 20px 10px 50px 20px;
overflow: hidden;
} 

.message { 
box-shadow: -2px 3px 3px #918350;
border: 1px solid #8ab113;
margin: 3px;
padding: 2px;
background: #ece5ae;
border-radius: 5px ;
width: 200px; }

.messageMenu{
margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
height: 0px; }
```

```html
<div class="message" style="box-shadow: none;">
<div class="messageMenu">
<div class="messageMenu1" > </div>
<div class="msgMenuBody" va="333" style="//display: none;"> </div>
<ul class="msgSub-menu"  >
<li><a href="#1">подпункт</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">подпункт</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">подпункт</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="messageBody">Я помню чудное мгновенье: Передо мной явилась ты, Как мимолетное виденье, Как гений чистой красоты. (про взаимоотношения между div-ами  :) )
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
.msgSub-menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  background: white;
}
```

причем даже z-index уже не обязателен, по сути выставив `position` вы сказали браузеру правильно позиционировать слои

```css
.msgSub-menu{ margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
width:70px;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid #8ab113;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #ece5ae;
Border-radius: 3px;
z-index: 1; }

.messageMenu1{ 
margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
width:24px;
height: 24px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
bottom: -0px; } 

.messageBody { 
margin: 20px 10px 50px 20px;
overflow: hidden;
} 

.message { 
box-shadow: -2px 3px 3px #918350;
border: 1px solid #8ab113;
margin: 3px;
padding: 2px;
background: #ece5ae;
border-radius: 5px ;
width: 200px; }

.messageMenu{
margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
height: 0px; }

.msgSub-menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="message" style="box-shadow: none;">
<div class="messageMenu">
<div class="messageMenu1" > </div>
<div class="msgMenuBody" va="333" style="//display: none;"> </div>
<ul class="msgSub-menu"  >
<li><a href="#1">подпункт</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">подпункт</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">подпункт</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="messageBody">Я помню чудное мгновенье: Передо мной явилась ты, Как мимолетное виденье, Как гений чистой красоты. (про взаимоотношения между div-ами  :) )
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно для блага сообщества, в 3-х словах о том почему оно так работает? Это внутренняя магия интерпретатора или какие-то объективные алгоритмы отображения, которые я просто не понимаю?

Comment: как я понимаю проблема в позиционировании - оно работает только когда указывается/задается свойство `position`, после этого можно манипулировать дочерними элементами (ставить выше/ниже), а без этого браузер элементы расставляет последовательно - чем позже встречается блок тем выше он становится над остальными блоками